# How can I save google maps api route information with symfony to database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, symfony, google-maps-api-3

Im learning Symfony and working on an application. I create a map and make direction information for destination point.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qckr.png)

I need to save this direction information to database. But I dont know how can I do. Maybe I convert this direction infotmation to array but I dont know how.
Here is script for map and calculate route

```
      `<script type="text/javascript">
var source, destination;
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function () {
    new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('txtSource'));
    new google.maps.places.SearchBox(document.getElementById('txtDestination'));
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ 'draggable': true });
});

function GetRoute() {
    var karabuk= new google.maps.LatLng(41.20488, 32.62768);

    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 11,
        center: karabuk
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('dvMap'), mapOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
    directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('dvPanel'));

    //*********DIRECTIONS AND ROUTE**********************//
    source = {lat:41.206373, lng:32.659379};
    destination = document.getElementById("txtDestination").value;

    var request = {
        origin: source,
        destination: destination,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
    });

    //*********DISTANCE AND DURATION**********************//
    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    service.getDistanceMatrix({
        origins: [source],
        destinations: [destination],
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidTolls: false
    }, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK && response.rows[0].elements[0].status != "ZERO_RESULTS") {
            var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance.text;
            var duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration.text;
            var dvDistance = document.getElementById("dvDistance");
            dvDistance.innerHTML = "";
            dvDistance.innerHTML += "Distance: " + distance + "<br />";
            dvDistance.innerHTML += "Duration:" + duration;

        } else {
            alert("Unable to find the distance via road.");
        }
    });

    var route=directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

}
```

`

I have defined a column in the database with type array. I didnt find how can I convert direction information to array and save it.

Answer (score 0):

Having a quick look, I'm guessing that this code

```
if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
}
```

... is what runs after it has fetched the directions from google. You can `console.log(response)` in there and check in the console, hopefully it should contain the data you need to store in the db.

Once you've grabbed it, POST it as JSON (using jQuery or something) to your symfony endpoint, and change the column type to the JSON type, and you should get it from there.